# Webtests do not run in teamcity build when external referenced dll are used in webtest

Tags: teamcity, webtest

We have developed few Webtests(.webtests) using Visual studio. We have created one build in Teamcity which compiles webtest solution and execute all webtests using MS runner.

It works fine.

But now we have created other class library project( custom plugin) under same solution and references its dll in our webtest project. When we are executing webtests from MS visual studio IDE, it works fine.
But when we execute them using our teamcity build it fails with error

***'Exception in PreWebTest event: Could not load file or assembly 'CustomPlugin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null''***

Any idea, how to make our Teamcity build work now?

Comment: Sounds like a generic reference issue.  Are you building the same solution configuration in TeamCity (ie. Debug / Release)? And is the new project set to build in the configuration running on TeamCity?

Comment: in Teamcity,  out build steps are like this
1)Compile Entire solution 
2) Using MS test runner execute all the webtests

Comment: It simply looks like that MSTestRunner is executing Webtests, but referenced DLL are not found by MSTest Runner